# How to remove special character from excel header in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read an excel file in pandas which has special characters in its header. I have a column with name like this "Col(≤9%)". How can I remove less than equal sign here?

If the ingest the file as it is, it fails with below error message

```
pandas._libs.lib.map_infer_mask UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2264' in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I can read it with `pd.read_excel("file.xlsx",engine="openpyxl")` w/o any issues.

Answer (score 0):

[image for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsJPU.png)

It doesn't have problem in my case.
If you still have problem, try to use

```
df = pd.read_excel("/path/to/your_file.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
```

If you are using xls, you can use other engine like `xlrd`, since

```
Your version of xlrd is 2.0.1. In xlrd >= 2.0, only the xls format is supported. Install openpyxl instead.
```

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: Sure, thanks for your suggestions. I will keep this in mind